# Smarty doesn't show array element of PHP session object

Tags: php, arrays, session, smarty, element

Code

```
{assign var=shipping_method value=$smarty.session.cart->sub_content}
{$shipping_method|print_r}
->{$shipping_method.products_name}<-
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
[customers_id] => 4
[products_name] => Abholung
[products_key] => shipping
[products_key_id] => 2
[products_model] => Abholung
[products_quantity] => 
[products_price] => 0
[products_tax_class] => 0
[products_discount] => 
[type] => shipping
[status] => 0
[sort_order] => 
[shop_id] => 
)
Array
-><-
```

There is something strange about the second "Array". 
But how I debug it and access the array element I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have debugged the array with foreach and found the solution. It appears that all the array elements are under a sub array "shipping":

```
        {foreach key=key0 item=val0 from=$shipping_method}
        {$key0}/{$val0}
        {foreach key=key item=val from=$val0}
        {$key}/{$val}
        {if $key=='products_name'}
        {assign var=shipping_method_name value=$val}
        {/if}
        {/foreach}
        {/foreach}

        {$shipping_method_name}
```

Will output:

```
                    shipping/Array
                    customers_id/4
                    products_name/Abholung  
                    products_key/shipping
                    products_key_id/2
                    products_model/Abholung
                    products_quantity/
                    products_price/0
                    products_tax_class/0
                    products_discount/
                    type/shipping
                    status/0
                    sort_order/
                    shop_id/
                    Abholung
```

So, to access the desired value, I would need to use this code:

```
    {$shipping_method.shipping.products_name}
```

The problem is solved, but why {$shipping_method|print_r} doesn't show a "shipping" sub-array. Is it a Smarty bug?